# JSON/HTTP response from a 3rd party URL using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am fairly new to web based development. How can i get a JSON/HTTP response from a 3rd party URL using Javascript/JQuery/AJAX? 
Also how do i access and use the information contained it? 
I have learned how to parse once i get the information. It is the fetching part i am struggling with.
Please try to explain wit any third party URL.

Comment: Yes. Basic JQuery ajax tutorial describe those scenarios with examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        xxx: {
            "xxx" : "xxx",
        }// <-- if you have data use this
    },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

This is the basic sample of cross domain call using jsonp. 
Think this might help.

**update** - Without json you can use below code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx', 
    // if you using below proxy passes use --> url: '/xxx',
    type:'POST', //or GET
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain : true,
    data: {
        //data goes with request
    },
    success: function(res) {
        //do stuff with res
    }
});
```

Then you will need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header correctly to allow the other server.

for apache server its like that

```
ProxyPass /xxx http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/xxx
ProxyPassReverse /xxx http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xx/xxx
```

Comment: This will only work if the 3rd party API implements JSONP. Many (probably most) don't.

Comment: @ambarox should not be jsonp: 'jsonp' its dataType:'jsonp'

Comment: @Tux thanks my mistake it is using jsonp is the name used as '?jsonp=' part of url. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar i edited the answer for Json also. Thanx for the tip buddy.

Comment: Since it's a 3rd party API, he can't change the Apache settings.